# Problemas con dropdown primeng, [option] dinamico ejecuta metodo infinitamente

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, typescript, primeng

Estoy creando una interfaz, y necesito que un dropdown sea dinamico, en la documentacion de PrimeNG, los ejemplos asumen que los valores de la variable para el atributo [option] se obtienen una vez (al ejecutarse en la carga de la pagina), pero yo quiero que sea dinamico y los valores sean retornado desde un metodo:

**component.html**

```
<p-dataView #dv [value]="listaPrincipal">
    <ng-template let-principal pTemplate="listItem">
        ...
        <p-dropdown [options]="obtenerDatos()"  [showClear]="true" placeholder="Seleccionar"></p-dropdown>
        ...
    </ng-template>
</p-dataView>
```

**component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'prueba-app',
    templateUrl: './component.html',
    providers: [
        ...
    ]
})
export class PruebaComponent implements OnInit{
    ngOnInit(): void {
        ...
    }

    obtenerDatos() {

        console.log("test");
    
        return [] //eliminé el metodo que devuelve los datos porque se estaba llamando esta funcion infinitamente
    
    }
```

Si ejecuto esto en la consola del navegador se imprime infinitamente "test"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo quiero que ese metodo se ejecute una sola vez. Como puedo lograr eso?

Comment: Quieres que se ejecute en cada iteración y al mismo tiempo quieres que se ejecute una sola vez.  Eso no es posible.

Comment: @Lobos, no hermano, en cada iteracion el metodo se tiene que ejecutar una vez, pero en cada iteracion se ejecuta muchas veces, de hecho esa imagen es resultado de una iteracion y el metodo ejecutandose mas de una vez en una iteracion

Comment: Entiendo. ¿La función `obtenerDatos` retorna datos diferentes en cada ejecución? Porque en el ejemplo siempre retornaría lo mismo.

Comment: @Lobos, es que yo le puse un console.log("test"), solo para enfatizar que se esta ejecutando la funcion varias veces por alguna razon (no por la iteracion)

Comment: Pues la razón por la que se ejecuta tantas veces es por la detección de cambios que hace Angular. Cuando ocurre un evento Angular analiza la plantilla y compara los datos con el modelo, si hay cambios entonces  actualiza la plantilla para reflejar el nuevo valor. El problema con la función es que Angular no puede saber su valor sin antes ejecutarla, así que hace eso varias veces debido a la detección de cambios.

Comment: @Lobos, en otras palabras, no es posible hacer metodo dinamico que devuelva valores?, como por ejemplo se puede hacer en lenguajes como JAVA, C# que se puede ejecutar un metodo desde una iteracion desde el frontend, para obtener listas dinamicas?

Comment: Sí se puede. Solo hay que diseñar el código de tal forma que sea  rápido de ejecutar. Por ejemplo la función `obtenerDatos` podría retornar los datos desde una caché y entonces no importa que se ejecute múltiples veces no impactará el desempeño de la aplicación. El problema no es que se ejecute muchas veces, el problema es que se pierda rendimiento si la función necesita mucho poder de cómputo.

Comment: @Lobos, sin importa la cantidad de veces que se ejecuta, dado que en el codigo original la funcion llama a un servicio (service.js) que obtiene una consulta desde una base de datos, si la llamada se hace con fecht o httpclient siempre se ejecuta varias veces

Comment: Sí, por eso te mencioné lo de la caché. Así solo se hace una petición la primera vez y de ahí los datos se traen de la caché. Otra cosa que puedes probar es hacer un componente que encapsule  el `p-dataView`, que reciba como input a `listaPrincipal` y que tenga `changeDetection: OnPush`, así no se ejecutaría la detección de cambios si `listaPrincipal` no cambia. https://angular.io/guide/change-detection-skipping-subtrees

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un array en lugar de la función obtenerDatos en la propiedad [options]

**component.html**

```html
<p-dataView #dv [value]="listaPrincipal">
    <ng-template let-principal pTemplate="listItem">
        ...
        <p-dropdown [options]="dropdownOptions"  [showClear]="true" placeholder="Seleccionar" optionLabel="name"></p-dropdown>
        ...
    </ng-template>
</p-dataView>
```

**component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'prueba-app',
    templateUrl: './component.html',
    providers: [
        ...
    ]
})
export class PruebaComponent implements OnInit{

    dropdownOptions: any[];

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.obtenerDatos();
    }

    obtenerDatos() {
        this.dropdownOptions = [{ value: 1, name: 'hello' }];
   }
}
```

Comment: Es que justamente eso es lo que no tengo que hacer, porque asi como me lo has planteado la ejecución del metodo "obtenerDatos()" se hace una vez, pero yo no necesito que se ejecute una vez, sino en cada iteracion del dataview